# Number of half-twist for higher order hexa-flexagons

Tags: general-topology, mobius-band

So, a hexa-flexagon is topologically equivalent to a Mobius Strip with 3 half-twist. Does this hold for a hexa-hexa-flexagon and higher order hexa-flexagons? How the heck do you unravel these and prove how many twist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've observed, the equation is 3n-6, where n is the number of faces. For every face that is added onto the original tri-hexaflexagon, more of the paper needs to stay "hidden" under half-twists, so 3 twists are added to hide the 3 sections of the new face.

Note that I've only observed hexaflexagons up to order 7, with the rest being my reasoning.